# Popup CRUD appication with angular 5/6

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, crud

I am using VS 2015 with angular 5 and Web API. There is a Master details screen. I want to add/modify details portion using modal popup and showing the details record in the table at same time which is very common. I have found many such examples in mvc and anguarjs but could not find proper example for anguar 4/5/6. Is there any link on that?

Thanks

Partha

Answer (score 1):

You can use a modal component from a library like https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals or angular material.

Just create the modal component and have a `showModal` function that recieve either the item ID or the item object.

Inside of it you can create a form and allow the user to update the entity. 
You can than use and `@Output` when the user submits the changes to notify the parent table component.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the following video,

[VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mIpWE7VV8A)

Comment: In this example there is no popup example.